# Hosting Jabbr on AppHarbor

Tags: signalr, appharbor

I've been trying to host Jabbr on AppHarbor. 
The guide [here](http://blog.appharbor.com/2012/4/30/run-your-own-group-chat-with-appharbor-and-jabbr) is not up to date as Jabbr doesn't have a dependency on Janrain anymore.

Steps I have done:

1. Installed the SQL Express addon.
2. I've pushed the latest Jabbr code from GitHub to the AppHarbor.
3. Changed the connection string with the full connections string from
   configuration.
4. Updated jabbr:encryptionKey and jabbr:verificationKey (as David Flower suggested).

The application manage to loads up, I can usethe default login screen, I can create a new user, but when the application crashes after login was successful (I think).

It is showing Server Error 
500 - Internal server error.

There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed.

When using the AppHarbor owns Errors pane, it shows nothing related.

What is the best way to debug this?

Thanks!

Ariel

Comment: The FAQ has suggestions for debugging errors: http://support.appharbor.com/kb/getting-started/frequently-asked-questions

Comment: I actually found out a solution, but I am not sure why it doesn't let me use my "Answer Your Question"

Comment: What was the solution as I am having the exact same issue.